# HTML - Alinhamento de DIVs, Poblema com alinhamento de DIVs e os itens dentro dela

Tags: html5, div, html-tags

Como eu posso alinhar botões e outros itens dentro de uma div? Sempre que eu coloco uma div na frente da outra seus itens dentro delas também estão ficando alinhados um em frente ao outro.
Para colocar uma div na frente da outra eu uso o 'display: inline-flex'.[image: aqui usei o display: inline-flex]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você adiciona `display: inline-flex;` ou `display: flex;` várias outras prioridades relacionadas são adicionadas.
Uma delas é `flex-flow: row;`, que faz os filhos serem aninhados em linha. Se você adicionar `flex-flow: column` na div os itens serão alinhados verticalmente.

De qualquer modo, é bom estudar um pouco sobre display flex para conhecer melhor as prioridades relacionadas.